# Using PostGIS to map multiple GPS tracks

Tags: postgis, geojson, query

I have a table which contains GPS track points from multiple vehicles.

What I want to do is to produce GeoJSON polygons to overlay each trip on a map over a range of dates.

My GPS table contains:

1. `id` - a unique id
2. `device_id` - a unique device id,
3. `vehicle_id` - a unique vessel id
4. `timecol` - the gps timestamp as a unix time stamp
5. `lat` - latitude
6. `lon` - longitude
7. `location` - geom location
8. `distance_from_depot` - km from the depot
9. `distance_from_depot_id` - a unique depot_id

When the NMEA strings are are imported to my database, I run a trigger which calculates the location, the nearest `depot_id`, distance from the nearest depot.

To generate the polygons, I currently have a query which I run which delivers the data to my server, which then has to take that data and manipulate it to GeoJSON features  with properties and geometry; a job which should really be done by the database layer.

My current query is contained within a function:

```
FUNCTION public.get_gps_tracks(p_vehicle_id integer, p_start_timestamp timestamp with time zone, p_end_timestamp timestamp with time zone)
RETURNS json
  LANGUAGE sql
AS $function$
    select 'GPS' as display_group, 
        array_agg(distinct entering_depot) as col4, 
        min(timecol) as start_time, 
        max(timecol) as end_time, 
        avg(lat) as data_a, 
        avg(lon) as data_b, 
    from gps_data 
    where 
        vehicle_id=p_vehicle_id 
        and timecol > p_start_timestamp  
        and timecol < p_end_timestamp 
    group by (round(timecol/300) sort by timecol;
$function$
```

I have had some success using a combination of `row_to_json`, `array_to_json` and `array_agg`, but not enough to get me that last 2% of the the problem.

How could I write this to return valid GeoJSON features, one trip per feature like the following GeoJSON . 
[image: Valid GeoJSON]

Perhaps the answer is to use a window function to detect a change in `{col4}` and group by that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your assistance. I have managed to beat this into submission with:

```
create or replace function public.map_vehicle_gps(p_vehicle_id integer, p_start_timestamp timestamptz, p_end_timestamp timestamptz)
returns json
language sql
as
$function$
select row_to_json(fc) gps from (select 'FeatureCollection' as type, 
array_to_json(array_agg(f)) as features
  from (select 'Feature' as type,
    json_build_object('start_time', min(coordinates.timecol), 'end_time', max(coordinates.timecol)) as properties,
    st_makeline(location::geometry order by timecol) as geometry
        from (select distinct on (vehicle_id, round(timecol / 300)) location,
          vessel_id, timecol, array_agg(distinct entering_depot) as in_depot
              from gps_data
              where "gps_data"."vessel_id" = p_vehicle_id
                and "gps_data"."timecol" between extract(epoch from p_start_timestamp::timestamp) and extract(epoch from p_end_timestamp::timestamp)
              group by location, vehicle_id, timecol
             ) as coordinates
        group by in_depot, vehicle_id
       ) as f) as fc;
$function$
;
```

I then call the function like this:

```
select public.map_vehicle_gps(6,'2019-12-04T00:00:00','2020-02-04T00:00:00');
```

Now, I just need to sort out the query plan and ensure its well indexed.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want the path of the vehicles on geojson format. This query may guide you,

```
SELECT vehicle_id,
    ST_AsGeoJSON(ST_MakeLine(loc ORDER BY timecol)) As gjson
FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT ON (vehicle_id, round(timecol/300)) * FROM gps ) As foo
GROUP BY vehicle_id;
```

You can use this query on your function to obtain the geometries, just need to add the filters with the inputs `vehicle_id`, `p_start_time` and `p_end_time`.

References:

1. [PostGIS Doc - ST_MakePoint](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_MakePoint.html)
2. [PostGIS Doc - ST_MakeLine](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_MakeLine.html)
3. [PostGIS Doc - ST_AsGeoJSON](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_AsGeoJSON.html)

Test Data

```
create table if not exists gps (
    id serial,
    device_id int,
    vehicle_id int,
    timecol int,
    lat float,
    lon float,
    loc geometry('Point', 4326),
    distance_from_depot int,
    distance_from_depot_id int
);
INSERT INTO gps (
    device_id,
    vehicle_id,
    timecol,
    lat,
    lon,
    loc,
    distance_from_depot,
    distance_from_depot_id
) VALUES
    (1, 1, 0, 0, 0, ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(0, 0), 4326), 0, 1),
    (1, 1, 100, 0.1, 0, ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(0.1, 0), 4326), 1, 1),
    (1, 1, 1000, 1, 0, ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(1, 0), 4326), 10, 1),
    (1, 1, 2000, 2, 0, ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(2, 0), 4326), 20, 1),
    (1, 1, 3000, 1, 0, ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(1, 0), 4326), 10, 1),
    (1, 1, 3900, 0.1, 0, ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(0.1, 0), 4326), 0.1, 1),
    (1, 1, 4000, 0, 0, ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(0, 0), 4326), 0, 1),
    (2, 2, 0, 0, 1, ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(0, 0), 4326), 0, 1),
    (2, 2, 1000, 0, 1, ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(0, 1), 4326), 10, 1),
    (2, 2, 2000, 0, 2, ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(0, 2), 4326), 20, 1),
    (2, 2, 2200, 0, 2.2, ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(0, 2.2), 4326), 22, 1),
    (2, 2, 2300, 0, 2.3, ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(0, 2.3), 4326), 23, 1),
    (2, 2, 2400, 0, 2.4, ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(0, 2.4), 4326), 24, 1),
    (2, 2, 3000, 0, 1, ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(0, 1), 4326), 10, 1),
    (2, 2, 4000, 0, 0, ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(0, 0), 4326), 0, 1);
```

Result

```
"vehicle_id","gjson"
1,"{""type"":""LineString"",""coordinates"":[[0,0],[1,0],[2,0],[1,0],[0.1,0]]}"
2,"{""type"":""LineString"",""coordinates"":[[0,0],[0,1],[0,2],[0,2.2],[0,2.4],[0,1],[0,0]]}"
```

Comment: Close but not quite. Each vehicle will have multiple paths. By checking 'col4' I can determine when a vehicle returns to a depot. So each path is defined as the time between depot visits. Also the GPS reports back every second, so the 'round(timecol/300)' allows me to reduce the resolution here to 5 min GPS readings. Some vehicles can be away from the depot for weeks on end...

Comment: How about having `GROUP BY vehicle_id, col4` in above query?

Comment: @Greg, I have updated the answer, and added some sample data and result.